# How to Create a Reusable Widget Card Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, card

I want to create a Card that is reusable with Image. Am I on the right track in the new type of Card? I do not know how to put the Image on the card. all the question regarding the reusable widget card type in stackoverflow and youtube seems old and i dont know if it is truly working in the newer version.

[Prototype Figma of My vision of Card in the HomePage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Psp.png)

[Here is the example for the clarifcation of the image on the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBiDG.png)

this is the previous code that I want to be scrapped because they are too many.

```
Container(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 75, 175, 78),
child: Center(
    child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    const SecondPage(
                        plantname: 'Bell Pepper')));
        },
        child: const Text(
        "Bell Pepper",
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 19,
            fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium',
            color: Color(0xffeeeeee)),
        )),
)),
```

This the new type of Card that I want to be the reusable. But I dont know how to put the image and make it better.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_splash/cli_commands.dart';

class ListViewCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final void Function()? onTap;
  final Image imageOfPlant;

  const ListViewCard(
      {super.key,
      required this.title,
      required this.onTap,
      required this.imageOfPlant,
      });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 75, 175, 78),
      elevation: 0,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),  
      semanticContainer: true,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent.withAlpha(30),
        onTap: onTap,
        //sizedBox of the card
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
            width: 150,        
            height: 200,
            child: Text(title,
              style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 19,
              fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium',
              color: Color(0xffeeeeee)),// textstyle
            ),),//text //SizedBox
          ], // <widget>[]
        ), // column
      ), //inkwell       
    ); // card
  }
}
```

Comment: image as background?

Comment: I would like to clarify the half of the background should be on the top of what I envision in  the "Prototype Figma of My vision of Card in the HomePage".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a asset folder in your project like this
   [image]
2. Add you image(jpeg, png or other) to this folder
3. Go to pubspec.yaml & add your asset path

## To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:

assets:
- assets/

4. Make this changes in your ListViewCard widget:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class ListViewCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final void Function()? onTap;
  final String imageOfPlant; //Change to String

  const ListViewCard(
      {super.key,
      required this.title,
      required this.onTap,
      required this.imageOfPlant,
      });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 75, 175, 78),
      elevation: 0,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),  
      semanticContainer: true,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent.withAlpha(30),
        onTap: onTap,
        //sizedBox of the card
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              imageOfPlant,
              height: 200,
              width: 150,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            SizedBox(
            width: 150,        
            height: 50,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(title,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 19,
                
                fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium',
                color: Color(0xffeeeeee)),// textstyle
              ),
            ),),//text //SizedBox
          ], // <widget>[]
        ), // column
      ), //inkwell       
    ); // card
  }
}
```

5. Use your card

   ListViewCard(
   title: 'Lotus', onTap: () {}, imageOfPlant: 'assets/image.jpg')

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: can I create a null safety in the images? it seems when I try that kind of thing it shows an error. that it is not a string when it is in null safety.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stack widget for this,

```dart
class ListViewCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final void Function()? onTap;
  final Image imageOfPlant;

  const ListViewCard({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.imageOfPlant,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 75, 175, 78),
      elevation: 0,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      semanticContainer: true,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent.withAlpha(30),
        onTap: onTap,
        //sizedBox of the card
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned.fill( // or positioned with top.left,bottom,right
              child: imageOfPlant,
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,//based on your need
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 200,
                    child: Text(
                      title,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 19,
                          fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium',
                          color: Color(0xffeeeeee)), // textstyle
                    ),
                  ), //text //SizedBox
                ], // <widget>[]
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ), // column
      ), //inkwell
    ); // card
  }
}
```

Also  [`GridTile`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/GridTile-class.html) has similar look.

Comment: the text alignment for the title is not right I dont know why. 
[This is the output of your answer](https://imgur.com/a/LV5SFAJ)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pass image widget inside constructor, pass its path, here I use asset image you can also network image too. Try this:

```
class ListViewCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final void Function()? onTap;
  final String imageOfPlantPath;

  const ListViewCard({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.imageOfPlantPath,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 2,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),

      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent.withAlpha(30),
        onTap: onTap,
        child: Container(
          height: 300,
          width: 150,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(imageOfPlantPath),
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
          ),
          child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
            return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: constraints.maxWidth,
              height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.5,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 75, 175, 78),
                border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                title,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 19,
                    fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium',
                    color: Color(0xffeeeeee)), // textstyle
              ),
            );
          }), //text //S,
        ),
      ), //inkwell
    ); // card
  }
}
```

**Note**: inside `LayoutBuilder` you can play with height and do what you want, I set half of the image here.

[image]

Instead of using Image as `DecorationImage`, you can use `Stack` that @YeasinSheikh said blew.

Comment: does using stack make a good performance boost because I am using a TensorFlow for our project we need a better performance?

Comment: I don't think so, It doesn't make difference.